# How to use AuthorizationChecker class instead of SecurityContext in symfony2

Tags: symfony, mpdf

I'm using mpadf & using symfony 2.7 version

But this error throws

> The Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext class is
>   deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0. Use
>   Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage
>   or Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker
>   instead.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Are you actually getting an error or just a depreciation notice.

Answer (score 3):

You must change:

```
$this->container->get('security.context')
```

to:

```
$user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
```

And remove from use section:

```
Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext
```

You find more info on Symfony blog page: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements